# How to define an exclusion zone for NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, version-7

I need to numerically integrate a differential equation and define two exclusion zones to stop the integration.  The *Mathematica* code looks like this :

```
NDSolve[{
    x'[s] == Bx[s],
    y'[s] == By[s],
    z'[s] == Bz[s],

    x[0] == initialDataX,
    y[0] == initialDataY,
    z[0] == initialDataZ

}, {x, y, z}, {s, 0, 1000},
Method -> Automatic,
MaxSteps -> Automatic,
StoppingTest -> (???)]
```

Now, the integration must **stop** if the vector **{x[s], y[s], x[s]}** goes inside one of two spheres of radius 1 located at **Source1** and **Source2**, respectively (the center of the spheres).  Currently, I'm using this **StoppingTest** constraint :

```
Sqrt[({x[s], y[s], z[s]} - Source[1]).({x[s], y[s], z[s]} - Source[1])] < 1 ||
Sqrt[({x[s], y[s], z[s]} - Source[2]).({x[s], y[s], z[s]} - Source[2])] < 1
```

That part is long, and I believe that it is clumsy.

What is the best way to define the **StoppingTest zone** in this case ?

Comment: For starters, it seems to me that the Sqrt's are superfluous. BTW note the existence of `SquaredEuclideanDistance`  and `EuclideanDistance`

Comment: Oops, just noticed V7 -- that was too long ago....You should probably mention that in the body of the question (assuming that's what the tag means).  For newer versions, the comment would be: I'm unaware of any option named `StoppingTest`.  Look up `WhenEvent`, paying particular attention to the action `"StopIntegration"`.

Comment: Yep, I could remove the **Sqrt**.  And **EuclideanDistance** also exists in version 7.

Comment: @bel The tag [tag:numerical-integration] explicitly includes questions about `NDSolve`.