# Multiple stopping constraints in NDSolve

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, numerical-integration, version-7, constraint

I need to numerically solve several differential equations, with several constraints, like this :

```
Coordinates[s_] := {x[s], y[s], z[s]}

NDSolve[{
    x'[s] == F[s], 
    y'[s] == G[s], 
    z'[s] == H[s], 
    x[0] == DataX, 
    y[0] == DataY, 
    z[0] == DataZ}, {x, y, z}, {s, 0, 500}, 
    Method -> Automatic, MaxSteps -> Automatic, 
    StoppingTest -> (
        EuclideanDistance[Coordinates[s], Source[1]] < 1 || 
        EuclideanDistance[Coordinates[s], Source[2]] < 1 ||
        EuclideanDistance[Coordinates[s], Source[3]] < 1 ||
        ...
        EuclideanDistance[Coordinates[s], Source[NumSources]] < 1
    )
]
```

Now, there are **NumSources** constraints of this type :

```
    EuclideanDistance[Coordinates[s], Source[k]] < 1
```

where **k = 1, 2, 3, ..., NumSources**.

How can I simplify that long part of constraints in the NDSolve defined above ?

This is probably basic, but I don't see how to simplify this.

**UPDATE :**  Just a picture to show off.  The magnetic field lines of an arbitrary number of magnetic dipoles (magnetized spheres) :

[image: 6 magnetized balls]

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your previous question, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105869/how-to-define-an-exclusion-zone-for-ndsolve?

Comment: It is related to that question, but it isn't the same.  Not a duplicate.  Or maybe it is ?  At first, I made that code just for 2 sources.  Now, I want to generalize the code for an arbitrary number of sources.

Comment: The first question was about some aspects for just 2 constraints.  Now, I'm trying to generalize the code for an arbitrary number of constraints.  Maybe it should be in the same question.

Comment: On a practical note, I don't suppose you can upgrade?  My feeling is that the [differential equations folks](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/differential-equations/topusers) no longer have access to V7, and things have changed so much that no one can test any ideas they might have.

Comment: So can you answer your previous question, then?  Your solution might help others suggest one to this question.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation for `StoppingTest`?

Comment: The other question was answered in the comments.  It was just about using the **EuclideanDistance** command !  And what is the best way to define stopping constraints in NDSolve ?  Apparently, **StoppingTest** isn't used anymore.

Comment: Does V7 have `Method -> {"EventLocator",...}`?  See http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveEventLocator.html.    It was replaced by `WhenEvent` in V9.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I'm not sure this is included in v7.  I'll check this later.  But is the **StoppingTest** command still supported in the latest version of Mathematica, for backward compatibility ?

Comment: No, StoppingTest is not in the docs (for V10.3.1 at least).  I don't know what the syntax is supposed to be, but I can guess its meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
StoppingTest -> 
 (Apply[
   Or,
   Table[EuclideanDistance[Coordinates[s], Source[i]] < 1, {i,1,NumSources}],
   {0}])
```

Comment: It doesn't appear to work well.  I'm getting lots of warning messages, and the output is all messy.  Is this compatible with **Mma version 7** ?  And why the {0} in the Apply ?

Comment: The {0} specifies the level. You can omit it (I copied and pasted it from another code). Despite the fact that the Apply command is updated in Mma version 10.3 it should work in this context in Mma 7. Have you defined the parameter s within Coordinates. Maybe s is a table and thus you have to give it as s[[i]]

Comment: Oh boy !  I just found the source of my problem !  This was trivial !  My bad !  Your suggestion appears to be working great now !

Comment: I'll mark your answer as THE answer in a few days, just in case someone give a simpler answer.

Comment: By the way, what should I use instead of **StoppingTest** ?  Apparently, this is an obsolete command.

Comment: @Cham Good, I couldn't see why this wouldn't work.

Comment: @Cham, for Mma 7 I am not sure how you can do it, but for Mma 10. 3 you can use WhenEvent

Comment: @demm, **WhenEvent** doesn't exist in version 7.  Can you confirm that **StoppingTest** is till there, in your newer version ?  I hope they still maintain backward compatibility !